# query for COLUMN_NAME LIKE "X" in sybase(Transact SQL)?

Tags: sybase

I need to automate writing a query in Sybase.

The table looks like this:

```
ID, A1, A2, A3, ..., A24, B1, B2, B3, ..., B24, etc.
```

I would like a query where the user can choose which columns are returned.  For instance, sometimes the user can choose all the `A*` columns, sometimes they can choose all the `B*` columns, sometimes they can choose any of the columns.

I need to write a query to read values from all the columns like:

```
SELECT a*,b* FROM Users
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE column_name LIKE a%, b%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: This isn't easy to implement and it's going to break very easily (by which I mean performance is going to be horrible, and it's a nice little route for SQL injection attacks if you're not very very careful). I **strongly** advise you to re-think what you're doing because there has to be a better way.

Second: The question as it stands doesn't actually make sense - what condition are you checking on the columns? `NOT NULL`? Also, do you want to `AND` or `OR` the conditions together?

To actually answer the question, though, to do this you'll need to write some dynamic SQL:

- Link `sysobjects` to `syscolumns`, filter by the table name and the fields you're interested in.
- Build a executable SQL statement using a cursor, then execute it.

Example below is, for each column in the `Users` table that starts with either 'A' or 'B', return all rows in the `Users` table that have a non-null value in any of those columns.

**Note:** I don't have a Sybase install handy to test this. Chances of it actually working are very low, but it should hopefully be enough to make you realise what a bad idea this is.

```
DECLARE @colname nvarchar(255),
        @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE '

DECLARE colcur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sc.name 
    FROM syscolumns sc 
            INNER JOIN 
         sysobjects so ON so.id = sc.id
    WHERE so.name = 'Users'
        AND so.type = 'U'
        AND (sc.name LIKE 'A%' OR sc.name LIKE 'B%')
    ORDER BY sc.name
OPEN colcur

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH colcur INTO @colname 
    SET @sql = @sql + @colname + ' IS NOT NULL OR '
END

DEALLOCATE colcur

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 3) -- need to trim off the trailing 'OR'

EXEC @sql
```